# Openid between parties in different networks

Tags: spring-boot, openid, adfs

I am creating a Spring Boot application with oauth2 (openid Connect with ADFS) authentication.

The application's server and the ADFS server reside in two different private networks that cannot communicate with each others.

The client (web browser) resides in a third network that can connect to the two others.

Is it possible to set up open id in this configuration?

I cannot figure out how to configure the SpringBoot application to avoid communication between the two servers, like it is with Saml for instance.

Comment: I will reach within the AAD team and come back to you.

Answer (score 0):

you could consider to use OpenID Connect implicit flow which avoids direct communication between application server and identity provider.